# where to download ngGrid js and css files

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

was following ng-grid's website http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/, however for step2, I can't event find out where to download the js and related css files. 
The github link seems only containing unable version 3.0 links. Where can I download the js and css files directly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This is the link you need](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/tree/2.x) You can either git checkout or download the zip (or use bower)

Comment: How to include them to my project. Like in my project i am using 2.0.11 version of ng-grid, now i just need to update to 3.0. How to do it?

Comment: ERROR: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/tree/2.x